# Spring Data not executing query

Tags: java, spring

I have an issue with query execution.

Here is my structure:

**ProductPrice**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="\"Product_price\"")
public class ProductPrice {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="product_price_id_seq",
            sequenceName="product_price_id_seq",
            allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator="product_price_id_seq")
    private long id;
    private Float price;
    private Date date_from;
    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
}
```

Here is my **ProductPriceDto**

```
@Data
public class ProductPriceDto implements Serializable {
    public Float price;
    public Date date;
}
```

Here Is my **PriceRepository**

```
public interface PriceRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductPrice, Long> {
    public static final String FIND_LAST_PRICE = "SELECT p.price, MAX(p.date_from) FROM ProductPrice p WHERE p.product = ?1 GROUP BY p.product";

    @Query(FIND_LAST_PRICE)
    ProductPriceDto findPrice(@Param(value = "product") Long product);

    @Override
    List<ProductPrice> findAll();
}
```

Now, when I am trying to execute `findPrice` on **PriceRepository**, I am getting an error of:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match
>   expected type [com.eternity.model.Product (n/a)]]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Despite good answers I've received from Wim, I decied to go with:

```
ProductPrice findFirstByProductIdOrderByDateFromDesc(@Param(value = "product") Long product);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query method expects a `Long` as the method argument, but in your JPQL query, you want a `Product`.

Change the query method argument to a `Product`.

Comment: This worked out great, but lead to another issue: SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "productpri0_.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function :(

Comment: @uksz you might want to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: I think it is because you have a `@ManyToOne` relation for that property, so this means that you have many `Price` results for a single `Product product`

Comment: @ddb, I do. Is there any other way to get only single price for a single product with max (date_from)?

Comment: @uksz, it's better that you do another question for this, as suggested by Wim Deblauwe

Comment: @WimDeblauwe, I've actually decided to go with: ProductPrice findFirstByProductIdOrderByDateFromDesc(@Param(value = "product") Long product);

Answer (score 1):

`ProductPrice` model class has a `Product product` property, not a `Long product`, for this reason you have that error.

you should change your **PriceRepository** has below

```
public interface PriceRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductPrice, Long> {
    public static final String FIND_LAST_PRICE = "SELECT p.price, MAX(p.date_from) FROM ProductPrice p WHERE p.product = ?1 GROUP BY p.product";

    @Query(FIND_LAST_PRICE)
    List<ProductPrice> findPrice(@Param(value = "product") Product product);

    @Override
    List<ProductPrice> findAll();
}
```